# C++ compiler gives an unexpected "No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous" error

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-errors

I was doing some code, pretty much for fun, and needed an exception class that supports formatting, so I started doing one myself. Here is the class:

Error.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>


namespace DynTyping {
    class Exception : public std::exception {

    protected:
        static const char* Name;
        const char* msg;

        virtual void Initialize(char* format, va_list args);

    public:
        Exception();
        explicit Exception(char* format, va_list args);
        explicit Exception(char* format, ...);
        explicit Exception(const char* format, va_list args);
        explicit Exception(const char* format, ...);
        const char* what();
    };

    class MemoryException : public Exception {
    protected:
        static const char* Name;
    };
}
```

Error.cpp:

```
#include "Error.h"


namespace DynTyping {

    const char* Exception::Name = "Exception";

    void Exception::Initialize(char* format, va_list args) {
        char msg[256];
        vsprintf_s(msg, format, args);
        char full_msg[256];
        sprintf_s(full_msg, "%s: %s", this->Name, msg);
        this->msg = full_msg;
    }
    Exception::Exception() : std::exception::exception() {
        this->msg = "Exception: an error occurred";
    }

    Exception::Exception(char* format, va_list args) : std::exception::exception() {
        this->Initialize(format, args);
    }
    Exception::Exception(char* format, ...) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        this->Initialize(format, args);
        va_end(args);
    }
    Exception::Exception(const char* format, va_list args) : std::exception::exception() {
        this->Initialize((char*)format, args);
    }
    Exception::Exception(const char* format, ...) : std::exception::exception() {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        this->Initialize((char*)format, args);
        va_end(args);
    }
    const char* Exception::what() {
        return this->msg;
    }
    const char* MemoryException::Name = "MemoryException";
}
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include "Error.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    using DynTyping::MemoryException;

    throw MemoryException("coucou");
}
```

But upon compiling, the compiler shows this error (Entire compiler output):

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Error.cpp
1>Test.cpp
1>C:\Users\XXX\Documents\XXX\Prog\cpp\Test\Test\Test.cpp(7,32): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'const char [7]' to 'DynTyping::MemoryException'
1>C:\Users\XXX\Documents\XXX\Prog\cpp\Test\Test\Test.cpp(7,32): message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>Generating Code...
1>Done building project "Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The command line for compilation was:

```
/JMC /permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files\Python310\include" /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\Test.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

The code was compiled using VS2019.

I hope I gave enough information for someone to help.

Comment: You haven't declared any non-default constructors for your `MemoryException` class.

Comment: Side note: rather than using C-Style variable arguments lists, see if you can take advantage of [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). When things go wrong, they go wrong at compile time rather than runtime, allowing you to fix the problem before the customer sees them.

Comment: The quick solution is to add `using Exception::Exception;` to your `MemoryException` class, as explained in the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks guys, my problem is now solved. I used the 'using Exception::Exception; ' solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a public constructor into your child class that transmits the args to your parent class :

```
class MemoryException : public Exception {
    protected:
        static const char* Name;
    public:
        MemoryException(const char* error_msg) : Exception(error_msg) {}
    };
```